# How to store token in mvc cookie and send it to api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am sending credentials to API which creates user then through MVC Login method i create token in Web API and return token in response to MVC now I want to store Token in MVC Cookie and again send it Web API when hitting API Controller authorized action.

Please suggest me these two things

Answer (score 3):

There's not a whole lot to work with here, but generally speaking, Web API diverges from MVC mostly in that it's fully REST-compliant, whereas MVC is not. REST-compliant applications are stateless (in other words: no session, no cookies, etc.). Everything the API endpoint needs must be sent along with the request either in the URL, the request headers or the request body. That means you could send the *value* of the cookie (not the cookie, itself) in the query string of a GET request or the body of a POST, or as is typical with REST API auth, as an `Authorization` HTTP header.

Comment: understand can you bit explain when i store token in mvc cookie and then i want to extract its value and send in get ot post parameter please help me

Comment: can you please tell me how to extract value from cookie and send it in request header